getting error POST https://example.online/wallet/paynow/upi 500 (Internal Server Error) in node js app
this code completely working fine on localhost but getting error on live node js server i hosted thiscode on vps server with aapanel
reacharge.ejs code

 const handleUPIGatewayPaymentRequest = async (moneyAmount) => {

            const response = await axios.post("/wallet/paynow/upi", {
                money: moneyAmount
            })

            const data = response?.data

            if (data === undefined || data === null) {
                alertMessage("Something went wrong!")
                return
            }

            if (data?.status === false) {
                alertMessage(data?.message)
                return
            }

            window.location.href = data?.urls?.web_url
        }


the code is working completely fine on localhost but when i uploded on server it's getting error on deposit money in wallet
paymentcontroller.js code


const initiateUPIPayment = async (req, res) => {
    const type = PaymentMethodsMap.UPI_GATEWAY
    let auth = req.cookies.auth;
    let money = parseInt(req.body.money);

    const minimumMoneyAllowed = parseInt(process.env.MINIMUM_MONEY)

    if (!money || !(money >= minimumMoneyAllowed)) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: `Money is Required and it should be ₹${minimumMoneyAllowed} or above!`,
            status: false,
            timeStamp: timeNow,
        })
    }

    try {
        const user = await getUserDataByAuthToken(auth)

        const pendingRechargeList = await rechargeTable.getRecordByPhoneAndStatus({ phone: user.phone, status: PaymentStatusMap.PENDING, type: PaymentMethodsMap.UPI_GATEWAY })

        if (pendingRechargeList.length !== 0) {
            const deleteRechargeQueries = pendingRechargeList.map(recharge => {
                return rechargeTable.cancelById(recharge.id)
            });

            await Promise.all(deleteRechargeQueries)
        }

        const orderId = getRechargeOrderId()

        const ekqrResponse = await axios.post('https://api.ekqr.in/api/create_order', {
            key: process.env.UPI_GATEWAY_PAYMENT_KEY,
            client_txn_id: orderId,
            amount: String(money),
            p_info: process.env.PAYMENT_INFO,
            customer_name: user.username,
            customer_email: process.env.PAYMENT_EMAIL,
            customer_mobile: user.phone,
            redirect_url: `${process.env.APP_BASE_URL}/wallet/verify/upi`,
            udf1: process.env.APP_NAME,
        })

        const ekqrData = ekqrResponse?.data

        if (ekqrData === undefined || ekqrData.status === false) {
            throw Error("Gateway er!#ror from ekqr!")
        }

        const newRecharge = {
            orderId: orderId,
            transactionId: 'NULL',
            utr: null,
            phone: user.phone,
            money: money,
            type: type,
            status: 0,
            today: rechargeTable.getCurrentTimeForTodayField(),
            url: ekqrData.data.payment_url,
            time: timeNow,
        }

        const recharge = await rechargeTable.create(newRecharge)

        console.log(ekqrData)

        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Payment Initiated successfully',
            recharge: recharge,
            urls: {
                web_url: ekqrData.data.payment_url,
                bhim_link: ekqrData.data?.upi_intent?.bhim_link || "",
                phonepe_link: ekqrData.data?.upi_intent?.phonepe_link || "",
                paytm_link: ekqrData.data?.upi_intent?.paytm_link || "",
                gpay_link: ekqrData.data?.upi_intent?.gpay_link || "",
            },
            status: true,
            timeStamp: timeNow,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)

        res.status(500).json({
            status: false,
            message: "Something went wrong!",
            timestamp: timeNow
        })
    }
}



help me fix this issue i am really new in this field and don't know how to fix it i try so many online articles solutions but not worked for me i am facing this error from last 9 days i tried chat gpt also but not working for me

What error message are you getting?  As it works on localhost but not in production you are probably missing a dependency.   Post a [mre] instead of a snippet.   We don't really care that you had the issue for 9 days.  What have you done to troubleshoot this?  Also, revise question to remove the duplicate problem statement.

on click handleUPIGatewayPaymentRequest code runs and in console i got error
POST https://example.online/wallet/paynow/upi 500 (Internal Server Error)

You need to capture the error that nodejs generates on stderr.
